# Certain plugins not working after updating from Grails 2 to 3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I upgraded my Grails project from 2.3.4 to 3.2.7.

My plugins Commentable and Rateable won't move over to the new project.

They are the latest versions, yet are still very old. The plugin folder can be found at the .m2 directory it says it is looking in, but I do not have a .jar

Has anyone experienced this before?

[The errors I get you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr1ux.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need Grails 3 specific versions of all your plugins, you can search [here](https://grails.org/plugins.html).

The 2 you mention don't seem to be available.

The upgrade docs talk about [upgrading them yourself](https://docs.grails.org/3.2.7/guide/upgrading.html#upgradingPlugins).

I've upgraded a couple of projects from Grails 2 to 3, for smaller projects with few dependencies it's not too bad but for larger projects with lots of plugin dependencies, with some of them not converted it was a mission & sucked up a lot of time & TBH wasn't worth it, my opinion only of course.